# Apply ORDER BY to UNION MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by, union

I'm trying to use the `ORDER BY` expression in my combination of `UNION`'s and am receiving the error

> "Expression #1 of ORDER BY contains aggregate function and applies to a UNION".

```
(SELECT 'SELECT' AS argument, count(argument) FROM mysql.general_log WHERE 
argument LIKE ("SELECT%"))
UNION
(SELECT 'INSERT' AS argument, count(argument) FROM mysql.general_log WHERE 
argument LIKE ("INSERT%"))
UNION
(SELECT 'UPDATE' AS argument, count(argument) FROM mysql.general_log WHERE 
argument LIKE ("UPDATE%"))
UNION
(SELECT 'DELETE' AS argument, count(argument) FROM mysql.general_log WHERE 
argument LIKE ("DELETE%"))
ORDER BY count(argument) ASC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
select * from
( query 1 union query 2 union query 3...)
order by x
```

**Edit**

You're also missing an alias for the count and for the outer query. The final query should look like this

That was enough for me to set up a working example on [rextester](http://rextester.com/KRFMU73731).

```
SELECT argument, cnt from
(
    (SELECT 'SELECT' AS argument, count(argument) as CNT FROM mysql.general_log WHERE 
    argument LIKE ("SELECT%"))
    UNION
    (SELECT 'INSERT' AS argument, count(argument) FROM mysql.general_log WHERE 
    argument LIKE ("INSERT%"))
    UNION
    (SELECT 'UPDATE' AS argument, count(argument) FROM mysql.general_log WHERE 
    argument LIKE ("UPDATE%"))
    UNION
    (SELECT 'DELETE' AS argument, count(argument) FROM mysql.general_log WHERE 
    argument LIKE ("DELETE%"))
) aa
ORDER BY cnt ASC;
```

There is a much easier solution though, that you can use since the arguments have all the same length:

```
select  substring(upper(argument), 1, 6) as argument, count(*) as cnt
from    mysql.general_log
group by substring(upper(argument), 1, 6)
order by cnt asc;
```

You can see that in action in the same rextester I linked above

Comment: Hi, I am greeted with the error "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: Thanks, however similar error "Expression 1 of ORDER BY contains aggregate function and applies to the result of a non-aggregated query"

Comment: That did the job, thanks so much. Why does MySql require us to use this alias though?

Comment: I have no clue, sorry. Glad it helped though :)